# Como romper un for o tomar el primer elemento de la lista

Tags: python, lista, python-3.7, diccionarios

Tengo la siguiente lista, compuesta por diccionarios por ende no puedo eliminar duplicados como en una lista normal. Naturalmente la lista tiene mucho elementos.

```
codigos = [1,2,3,4,5...]

recursos = [{'Title': 'aaa'}, {'img': 'http:foto.png'}, {'Abstract': 'bbb'}, {'title': 'aaa'}, {'Discipline': 'area uno'}, {'ttitle': 'aaa'}]
```

De momento

```
listaSalida = []
for i in codigos:
 # consulta con funcion
 for detalle in recursos:
  for clave, valor in detalle.items():
   if(clave == 'Title' or clave == 'title' or clave == 'ttitle'):
    listaSalida.append((i, valor))
    # aqui se guardaria el titulo junto a ese numero
    break
    # para pasar al siguiente recurso
```

Mi idea era que **break** encontraba una coincidencia y finalizaba pero no... lo mismo ocurre con **pass**, si lo hacen funcionar así como esta y **suponiendo** este bien la salida seria

```
listaSalida = [(1, 'aaa'), (2, 'aaa'), (3, 'aaa')...]
```

naturalmente la lista **recursos** con diccionarios va cambiando, por eso el 2do elemento (titulo) iría cambiando, a algo como: "(2, 'bbb'), (3, 'ccc')"

++
En resumen quiero que cuando encuentre el **titulo** independientemente de como este escrito lo agregue, solo a ese, y pase al siguente porque con esa **condición** los agrega a todos.

PD: el porque el titulo se "repite" tanto fue un problema en la recolección de datos.

Comment: Pues no está del todo clara la pregunta. ¿Por qué iteras también en la lista `codigos`? ¿Qué representa? Los diccionarios que hay dentro de `recursos`¿son todos de una sola clave? (porque si así fuera no sé por qué iteras por `detalle.items()`? ¿Cuántos elementos esperas que tenga al final `listaSalida`?  ¿En `listaSalida` sólo deben aparecer títulos? ¿Qué pintan el resto de campos? ¿no son importantes para ti? Quizás si pusieras un ejemplo algo más complicado (y más cercano a tus datos reales) esto se entienda mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La declaración [`break`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) solo sale de un bucle. Tú tienes 3 en total, y solo sales del último, creo que quieres salir también del segundo.

Para eso puedes usar una variable que sea `True` cuando hayas encontrado lo que quieres. En el código de abajo tengo una variable `salir` para eso:

```py
listaSalida = []
for i in codigos:
    salir = False

    # consulta con funcion
    for detalle in recursos:
        for clave, valor in detalle.items():
            if(clave == 'Title' or clave == 'title' or clave == 'ttitle'):
                listaSalida.append((i, valor))
                salir = True
                break
        if salir:
            break
```

Comment: si eso mismo ha sido, lo probé varias veces para verificar que funcione, gracias